# Does Visual Studio Code C/C++ "force include" work?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code v.1.53.2 with C/C++ v.1.2.2, all other extensions disabled.
The issue is force include is ignored when building. Intellisense recognizes it though:
[image: defined and unrecognized]

Please can you provide any workaround? One that doesn't imply manual `#include`-ing as files would have to be modified and I want to preserve the compatibility to MSVS 2019 and Eclipse.
I also posted a comment at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/2888 but I realized that being closed it might not be read.

I tried the workaround presented there, i.e. using `browse` but it doesn't work.

c_cpp_properties.json has this configuration:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.27.29110/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",
            "forcedInclude": ["${workspaceFolder}/Globals.h"],
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x64"
        },
        {
            "name": "G++ config",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/g++.exe",
            "forcedInclude": ["${workspaceFolder}/Globals.h"],
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
            "compilerArgs": [
                "-m64",
                "-Wall"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

This can be reproduced by:

1. Create a cpp file with `int main() {return VAL;}`;
2. Create `Globals.h` in project root with `#pragma once #define VAL 12`;
3. Use `"forcedInclude": ["${workspaceFolder}/Globals.h"]` in c_cpp_properties.json;

EDIT:
I'm building with:

```
"tasks": [
        {
            "label": "[EXE] g++ build all files",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-m64",
                "-O3",
                "-Wall",
                "${fileDirname}/**.cpp",
                "-o",
                "Main.exe"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "manual labour"
        }
        ]
```

EDIT2:

1. I noticed that having the 2 configurations, one with MS' cl.exe and one with g++.exe, using the `forcedInclude` property in the config for MS makes studio code intellisense see the defines in spite of using the g++ config.
2. In tasks.json, in "args", I tried `"-include", "${workspaceFolder}/Globals.h"` which I think it's the g++ correspondent of force include. The project built successfully. But intellisense still doesn't know:
   [image]
   So, macros are properly expanded in all source files, project builds ok but with errors which never go away. So, problem still unsolved.

Comment: `c_cpp_properties.json` is for linting. Only.

Comment: @sweenish Where would `"forcedInclude": ["${workspaceFolder}/Globals.h"]` go then?

Comment: It goes in that file. You need a build system.

Comment: How are you building the code?

Comment: @AlanBirtles I've updated the question with the code.